# android - com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response

Tags: android, android-studio, heroku, parse-platform, parseexception

I am using Parse with Heroku in my application. But I am getting the error, `com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response`.

i did a lot of research, and found that some people had problem in the format of the `server(url)`, where they needed to add `/` after `/parse`. But I have the correct format of the URL written in the code.

This is my code below:

```
  Parse.initialize(new 
  Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("APP_ID")
            .clientKey(null)
            .server("https://abc-xyz.herokuapp.com/parse/").build()
  );

  ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
  gameScore.put("score", 1337);
  gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
  gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
  gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
          if (e == null) {  // the error is always 'bad JSON response' here
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
          } else {
              Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
          }
      }
  });
```

Also, just to give you another update,

I am getting the same error. I was using compile `'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'`, but I changed it to compile `'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'`, therefore, it gives `'cannot resolve symbol'` on `server(url).build()`.

Also, if I am using, `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.0'`, I am getting the same error, i.e.,
`'cannot resolve symbol'` on `Configuration`, in the above code.

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}
```

Can somebody provide some solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is caused due to wrong `clientKey` and `applicationId`.

Comment: Hi Anubhav, i am using the same `clientKey` and `appId`, that is being used on Heroku dashboard.

Comment: do u have any other solution for this issue??

Comment: I think this issue still exits in Parse SDK. you can take a look at this link  [link]https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/334